# Crockford Chapter 7 - make_a_matcher

Tags: javascript, regex

In the book on page 72, we have this example (see below). But when I test it in FF and also in NodeJS actually `y.lastIndex` is `0` and also `x === y` is `false`.

Any idea why this mismatch here between the information in the book and the actual behavior?

```
function make_a_matcher() {
    return /a/gi;
}
var x = make_a_matcher();
var y = make_a_matcher();
// Beware: x and y are the same object!
x.lastIndex = 10;
document.writeln(y.lastIndex); // 10
```

Comment: Hum... this shouldn't write 10.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the book handy, but for the code shown `x` and `y` are definitely _not_ the same object, so `0` is the correct output and `x === y` should be `false` just like you found when you ran it. Is that code a direct quote from the book? If so that's an error in the book. (As an aside, does Mr. Crockford really use `document.writeln()` in his examples?)

Comment: In my system, Both `node`, `chrome` produce `0` for `y.lastIndex`.

Comment: Actually I have just looked and the book and I am surprised it says exactly like the OP mentioned, I am confused now.

Comment: You mean there's a document.writeln in Crockford's book ? Damn...

Comment: I guess I'll have to write a new book, called "'Javascript The Good Parts' The Good Parts"

Comment: In unconfirmed errata on O'Reilly's website: http://oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596517748

Comment: Yes, this code is direct copy from the book. And yes, he uses document.writeln throughout the book for displaying output. Is it possible the author was correct in 2008 but not any more due to some change in the JavaScript language itself over the next 5 years?

Answer (score 3):

Well this is weird, but I think it is an error, unless old Javascript interpreters cached regular expression literals and returned the same instance.

Well as @fgb has mentioned in his comment, [The ES3 standard allowed interpreters to cache the literals, but this was restricted in ES5](http://whereswalden.com/2010/01/15/more-es5-incompatible-changes-regular-expressions-now-evaluate-to-a-new-object-not-the-same-object-each-time-theyre-encountered/), Thank you again @fgb.

Anyway it is posted as an [Unconfirmed Errata](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596517748).

Comment: Caching regular expression literals and returning the same instance would be a bug, as there's an internal state depending on the operations you do with the regex.

Comment: @dystroy I see, that's why I said it is weird :).

Comment: Caching literals was allowed in ES3, but not ES5. See: http://whereswalden.com/2010/01/15/more-es5-incompatible-changes-regular-expressions-now-evaluate-to-a-new-object-not-the-same-object-each-time-theyre-encountered/

Comment: @fgb Thank you very much for the enlightening link.

Comment: Thank you. So this is some change in the language which happened since the book was written.

Comment: @dystroy Check what fgb had to say.

Comment: @Sniffer thanks. This really was a stupid optimization... It could have been done "behind the scene", at the very least, not making only one object in js...

Comment: @dystroy Yes it was, at least they have done it wrong. You are welcome.